# VM Viewer cannot open console: "A connection will not be made because credentials may not be sent to the remote computer"

Tags: hyper-v, system-center, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

since some time - after we installed the latest Windows Updates on the Hyper-V hosts - we are having serious issues opening the remote console of a VM running on the Hyper-V hosts.

Scenario:

- Clients are Windows 7 + all Windows Updates on a Domain
  "corporate.net"
- Hyper-V hosts are Windows 2012R2 + all Windows
  Updates + SCVMM (2012 SP1) on a different domain "testcenter.net"

On the clients we either use the Website (https://sc.testcenter.net) or the SystemCenter VMM Console to connect to the SystemCenter using users from the "testcenter.net" domain. Connection works fine and I have control over the VMs as wanted. However, when I try to open the console of a VM I get the following error message:

"A connection will not be made because credentials may not be sent to the remote computer. For assistance, contact your system administrator. (0x0F08, 0x0000)"

Firewall is not an issue (any-any allow).

Note: We have a one-way trust from "corporate.net" to "testcenter.net" but for Hyper-V access we are mostly using the "testcenter.net" users.

Note2: The users we are testing with are Domain Admins within "testcenter.net"

Note3: It works on one Windows 7 client of my collueage to *some* of our Hyper-V servers but not with all; it does not work to any Hyper-V servers on my other clients.